# PL/SQL Block statement to populate table

Tags: oracle, plsql, concatenation, sqlplus

I am very new to PL/SQL and this one has me stumped. In SQLPLUS, I need to "Use a PL/SQL block to populate the Description column by selecting the combinations from your OLTP_VEHICLES table and then inserting the combinations into your new
VEHICLES table, which would best be performed via a cursor in a loop." This is what I have:

```
CREATE TABLE OLTP_Vehicles (
VIN VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
trade_ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
type VARCHAR(10),
make VARCHAR(15),
model VARCHAR(15),
where_from VARCHAR(30),
wholesale_cost NUMBER(8,2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (VIN),
CONSTRAINT UC_Sale_Vehicles UNIQUE (VIN,trade_ID));

CREATE TABLE Vehicles (
vehicle_Code VARCHAR2(10),
description VARCHAR2(100),
PRIMARY KEY (vehicle_Code));

CREATE SEQUENCE veh_code_seq
MINVALUE 1
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
CACHE 20;

--PL/SQL Block
**SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
BEGIN
    FOR i in 1..10
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO Vehicles (vehicle_Code, description)
        VALUES veh_code_seq.NEXTVAL, (SELECT CONCAT(make, ', ',model) AS 
        description FROM OLTP_Vehicles); 
    END LOOP;
END;
/**
```

But I am getting this error:

VALUES veh_code_seq.NEXTVAL, (SELECT CONCAT(make, ', ',model) AS description FROM OLTP_Vehicles);
*
ERROR at line 5:
ORA-06550: line 4, column 50:
PL/SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values
ORA-06550: line 4, column 1:
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

I am assuming this is my SELECT CONCAT statement that is causing the issue. How can I pull in two columns from another table and insert them as one column in a new table?

**MODIFIED Statement**

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE
CURSOR c_VIN IS SELECT DISTINCT VIN FROM OLTP_Vehicles;
BEGIN
    FOR c1 in c_VIN
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO Vehicles (vehicle_Code, description)
        VALUES (veh_code_seq.NEXTVAL, (SELECT make || ', '||model AS 
        description
        FROM OLTP_Vehicles 
        WHERE VIN = c1.VIN));
    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

RESULTS:

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM Vehicles ORDER BY vehicle_Code DESC;

VEHICLE_CODE    DESCRIPTION
--------------- ------------------------------
9               Chevrolet, Camaro
8               Chevrolet, Colorado
7               Dodge, Challenger
6               Ford, Fusion
50              Ford, Taurus
5               Chevrolet, Silverado
49              Chevrolet, Tahoe
48              Chevrolet, Colorado
47              Chevrolet, Colorado
46              Chevrolet, Silverado
45              Dodge, Ram

VEHICLE_CODE    DESCRIPTION
--------------- ------------------------------
44              Chevrolet, Impala
43              Chevrolet, Silverado
42              Chevrolet, Silverado
41              Chevrolet, Silverado
40              Chevrolet, Malibu
4               Ford, Focus
39              Dodge, Ram
38              Chevrolet, Camaro
37              Ford, F-350
36              Dodge, Ram
35              Ford, Fiesta

VEHICLE_CODE    DESCRIPTION
--------------- ------------------------------
34              Dodge, Dakota
33              Ford, F-150
32              Chevrolet, Silverado
31              Chevrolet, Suburban
30              Ford, Expedition
3               Dodge, Durango
29              Chevrolet, Colorado
28              Chevrolet, Tahoe
27              Dodge, Ram
26              Chevrolet, Silverado
25              Dodge, Charger

VEHICLE_CODE    DESCRIPTION
--------------- ------------------------------
24              Chevrolet, Silverado
23              Ford, F-150
22              Chevrolet, Tahoe
21              Chevrolet, Suburban
20              Ford, Expedition
2               Ford, Focus
19              Dodge, Charger
18              Chevrolet, Corvette
17              Chevrolet, Tahoe
16              Chevrolet, Suburban
15              Ford, F-250

VEHICLE_CODE    DESCRIPTION
--------------- ------------------------------
14              Ford, Edge
13              Chevrolet, Colorado
12              Chevrolet, Corvette
11              Dodge, Charger
10              Chevrolet, Camaro
1               Ford, Fusion

50 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Now I need to figure out how to get the distinct make and model as they do not connect with the VIN and I need to figure out why the vehicle_Code is not starting at 1 and DESC order.

Answer (score 1):

The concat function only takes two parameters, not three.  Just replace with the string concatenation operator ||   Example:

```
BEGIN
    FOR i in 1..10
    LOOP
        INSERT INTO Vehicles (vehicle_Code, description)
        VALUES (veh_code_seq.NEXTVAL, (SELECT make||', '||model AS 
        description FROM OLTP_Vehicles) ); 
    END LOOP;
END;
```

However, that is not the end of your problems.  Your embedded SELECT statement does not make sense.  It is reading all the rows from OLTP_Vehicles on each loop
iteration.  Was that your intent?

Comment: I am supposed to find all the combinations of the make and model from the OLTP_Vehicles table and have it inserted into the Vehicles table. This is not necessarily how many rows are in the OLTP_Vehicles table though as the make and model were randomly assigned. I see your point on how I am reading all the rows and not just the distinct rows. I need to figure that one out...

Answer (score 0):

Try below block code,

```
Declare
cursor c_vin is select distinct vin /*unique id*/ from OLTP_Vehicles;

begin

for c1 in c_vin loop

INSERT INTO Vehicles
(vehicle_Code, description)
SELECT veh_code_seq.NEXTVAL, make ||', '|| model
FROM OLTP_Vehicles where vin=c1.vin;


End loop;
commit;

End;
```

Comment: For some reason, the vehicle_code is not starting and incrementing by 1, and the make and model are not distinct. I realized I forgot to put that into my initial question. I modified my question with my results.

Comment: Actually, Whenever you select  "veh_code_seq.NEXTVAL" it increment the sequence by one no matter you insert it into your table or not. So, whenever you will play with your select query the sequence will get incremented.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is to use below query to insert data into Vehicles table If it is a one time work.

```
insert into Vehicles 
select  rownum,  description from ( select  distinct initcap(trim(make)) ||', '||initcap(trim(model)) description from OLTP_Vehicles) ;
```